# multiple accounts linked with the same route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I want to link one route53 (with multiple hostedZones) to two different accounts from amazon "aws". Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: If you want an answer I think you are probably going to have to be a little more thorough in your question. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As @MattO'Brien said. Route53 is basically just a DNS service, so you can always add records that point to any IP address, CNAME, etc. inside or outside of AWS. If you need to do anything more than that then you need to provide a lot more detail of what you are trying to do.